# Creating a basic file server for video editing on a limited budget?

Tags: video, raid, video-editing, file-server

I have a friend who fried an external 1TB HD (connected to a Mac) which was used to store video files that they were editing.

Are there any specifications that would describe how to create a basic file server on a limited budget?  My thought would be to use a old PC tower case and add in some sort of basic RAID controller with a series of harddrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just worried about problems from wearing out your disk again, you can get a plain old external disk enclosure for around $50 that supports 2 mirrored disks (disks not included).  This protects you against a single disk failure.

---

**Update to answer the comment:**

- [NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007705&IsNodeId=1&srchInDesc=raid&page=1&bop=And&ActiveSearchResult=True&Order=PRICE&PageSize=20)
- [Tiger-Direct](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/Category/guidedSearch.asp?CatId=2777&sel=Detail;212_186_3359_3359)
- [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_n_6?rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A!493964%2Cn%3A541966%2Cp_6%3AATVPDKIKX0DER%2Cp_n_condition-type%3A2224371011%2Cn%3A172456%2Cn%3A160354011&bbn=172456&ie=UTF8&qid=1298482700&rnid=172456#/ref=sr_st?keywords=raid&qid=1298482715&rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A!493964%2Cn%3A541966%2Cn%3A172456%2Cn%3A160354011%2Ck%3Araid&sort=price)
- [CDW](http://www.cdw.com/shop/search/results.aspx?wclss=TA3&Attr1722=TRANS50005949&SortBy=PriceAsc)

The key thing you're looking for here is support for RAID 1.  I couldn't image ever buying a single disk enclosure any more, unless you're really concerned about portability or have a separate real backup solution (RAID 1 is not a real backup).

You can also search for a NAS (Network Attached Storage) device.  These will come with disks and are likely easier to set up.

Comment: What would the enclosures be called?  Who would carry these enclosures (ie TigerDirect)?

Comment: @John see my update